# determine the file name of open (working) file

Tags: vbscript

Is there any way(or is it possible) to get the file name of currently working file.
As an example I opened "myPicture.png" file and if I run the script it should get "myPicture.png" as the result

Comment: There is no such thing as a "currently working file". You could use Sysinternals' [`handle`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896655) utility to enumerate open handles to files, but that's about it. This will only detect files which the application keeps opened, though. It won't detect files where the application reads the entire content and then closes the handle(s).

Comment: If i could say which process the file got opened, is there any possibility ?

Comment: If the program exposes a COM object that allows VBScript to enumerate its open files: perhaps. Otherwise no.

Answer (score 0):

If a program has a file open you can use this procedure to find which program.

Start - All Programs - Accessories - Right click Command Prompt and choose Run As Administrator. Type (or copy and paste by right clicking in the Command Prompt window and choosing Paste).

```
openfiles /local on
```

Reboot

```
openfiles /query /v
```

Comment: But I already know the Program, What i need is file name, As example I could say, i need to know the file name of notepad text file name which opened with notepad

Comment: @narak: `openfiles` with `/local` set to `on` does the exact same as the `handle` utility.